# Cant get form inputs side by side to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, web-deployment

I tried a bunch of things like playing with padding and margin, I used tables and even displayed as an inline and inline-block but I have also tried to div different parts of the code hoping that separating the code I could manipulate it better but no results. I can't get my inputs to be side by side. Here is a link to the code on codepen.io. can someone please give me some help!

```css
/* color:#00a786 lighter green */
/* color:#005242 dark green for buttons */
/* color:003027 dark green background */


* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    background-color: #fff;
}

body {
    background: #ede6e6;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif ;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#fff;
}

/* --------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------- */
header{
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(../img/heder_photo_2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  right:-20px;
  left: -20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;

background-attachment: fixed;
position: absolute;
z-index: 80;

}

.row{
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;


}

}
/* --------------------------------TOP-LEFT------------------------------------- */
.top-left{

  float:left;
}
.top-left ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: -80px;
  padding-bottom: 30px

}


/* -------------------------------SOCIAL-LINKS------------------------------------- */
.social-links ul {
display:inline;
padding-left: 150px;

}
.social-links li{
  font-size: 100%;


}

.social-links li:hover,
.social-links li:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a786;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}



/* -------------------------------TOP-RIGHT------------------------------------- */
.top-right{
  float:right;

}
.top-right  {
float: right;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}


.top-right li {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 200;
}
  .top-right li:hover,
  .top-right li:active{
color:#005242;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}


.top-right li:first-child{
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: thin;
}
.top-right li:last-child{
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: thin;
}
/* -------------------------------H1------------------------------------- */

.main-header{
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  float:left;

}
.header-text{
  display: inline-block;
}

h1{
font-size: 90%;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;


}
span{
  color:#00a786
}

/* -------------------------------MAIN-NAV------------------------------------ */
.main-nav{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.main-nav-links{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav-links li:hover,
.main-nav-links li:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a786;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;

}
/* -------------------------------MAIN-SECTION------------------------------------ */
.main-section{




}
.main-content{
  text-align: center;


}
.content{
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}
.content h2{

  font-size: 100%;
}

.content p{
  font-size: 60%
}

/* -------------------------------BUTTONS------------------------------------ */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited
  input[type=submit]{
    display: inline-block;
    padding :10px 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

    transition: background-color 0.2s,border 0.2s,color 0.2s;
    msargin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited,
input[type=submit]{
    background-color: #00a786;
    border: 1px solid #005242;
    color: #fff;

  }
    .btn-full:hover,
    .btn-full:active,
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #005242;
        border: 1px solid #005242;
        color: #fff;

    }

    .search-btn:link,
    .search-btn:visited
    input[type=submit]{
        display: inline-block;
        padding :10px 30px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        font-size: 60%;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        transition: background-color 0.2s,border 0.2s,color 0.2s;

    }
  .search-btn:hover,
.search-btn:active,
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #005242;
        border: 1px solid #005242;
        color: #fff;

    }
/* -------------------------------Section-Search------------------------------------ */
    .section-Search{
      background-color: #003027;
      border: 2px solid #003027;
      border-radius: 3px;
      position:relative;
      left:200px;
      right:20px;
      top: 500px;
      height: 30vh;
      width: 600px;
      z-index: 99;

}
   .main-Search{
padding:30px 10px;
  display: inline;

}

.col1{

}

.col3{


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styling.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/fonts/Aileron/">
    <title>Williams Rental Propertie's</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <!--- TOP LEFT-------->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="top-left">
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fas fa-phone-volume icon-contact ">(312)343-8748</i></li>
                <li><i class="far fa-envelope icon-contact">WilliamsRentalProperties</i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- SOCIAL LINKS-------->
        <div class="social-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </a></i></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- TOP RIGHT-------->
        <div class="top-right">
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fas fa-user "> <a href="#"> Register</i></a></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"><a href="#">Login</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- main Header-------->

    <div class="main-header">
        <div class="header-text">
            <h1>Williams <span> Rental</span> Properties</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="main-nav">
        <div class="main-nav-links">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Featured List</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> About Us</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Pages</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="main-section">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Let Us Find You Your Dream Home!</h2>
                <p>Search real estate property records, houses, condos, land and more .
                Find property info from the most comprehensive source data.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">View Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </header>

  <section class ="section-Search">
    <div class="main-Search">



    <form class="Search" action="index.html" method="post">
        <label for="address"></label>

        <!--- city-------->
        <div class="col1">
            <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="keyword,zipcode">
        </div>
        <!--- city-------->
        
        <div class="col2">
            <label for="city"></label>
            <select class="city" name="city">
                <option value="city">city</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <!--- state------->
        <div class="col3">
            <label for="state"></label>
            <select class="state" name="state-form">
                <option value="state">state</option>
        </div>

        <!--- search button------->
        <a class="search-btn" href="#">Search</a>

        </select>

    </form>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that your last closing `</select>` tag –at the *state* field– is misaligned. It should be closed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You have them in different `div` elements and `div` elements are block-level (appear on their own line). Just place them in the same `div`.

Also (FYI), you aren't using the `label` element correctly. The `for` attribute value in a `label` needs to match the `id` attribute value of the form element that the `label` is "for"`.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
      background-color: #fff;
}

body{
      background: #ede6e6;
      margin:0 auto;
      font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif ;
    }

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
}
li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color:#fff;
}
/* --------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------- */
header{
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(../img/heder_photo_2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  right:-20px;
  left: -20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;

background-attachment: fixed;
position: absolute;
z-index: 80;

}

.row{
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;


}

}
/* --------------------------------TOP-LEFT------------------------------------- */
.top-left{

  float:left;
}
.top-left ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: -80px;
  padding-bottom: 30px

}


/* -------------------------------SOCIAL-LINKS------------------------------------- */
.social-links ul {
display:inline;
padding-left: 150px;

}
.social-links li{
  font-size: 100%;


}

.social-links li:hover,
.social-links li:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a786;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}



/* -------------------------------TOP-RIGHT------------------------------------- */
.top-right{
  float:right;

}
.top-right  {
float: right;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}


.top-right li {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 200;
}
  .top-right li:hover,
  .top-right li:active{
color:#005242;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}


.top-right li:first-child{
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: thin;
}
.top-right li:last-child{
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-width: thin;
}
/* -------------------------------H1------------------------------------- */

.main-header{
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  float:left;

}
.header-text{
  display: inline-block;
}

h1{
font-size: 90%;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;


}
span{
  color:#00a786
}

/* -------------------------------MAIN-NAV------------------------------------ */
.main-nav{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.main-nav-links{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav-links li:hover,
.main-nav-links li:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #00a786;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s;

}
/* -------------------------------MAIN-SECTION------------------------------------ */
.main-section{




}
.main-content{
  text-align: center;


}
.content{
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}
.content h2{

  font-size: 100%;
}

.content p{
  font-size: 60%
}

/* -------------------------------BUTTONS------------------------------------ */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited
  input[type=submit]{
    display: inline-block;
    padding :10px 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 60%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

    transition: background-color 0.2s,border 0.2s,color 0.2s;
    msargin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited,
input[type=submit]{
    background-color: #00a786;
    border: 1px solid #005242;
    color: #fff;

  }
    .btn-full:hover,
    .btn-full:active,
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #005242;
        border: 1px solid #005242;
        color: #fff;

    }

    .search-btn:link,
    .search-btn:visited
    input[type=submit]{
        display: inline-block;
        padding :10px 30px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        font-size: 60%;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        transition: background-color 0.2s,border 0.2s,color 0.2s;

    }
  .search-btn:hover,
.search-btn:active,
    input[type=submit]{
        background-color: #005242;
        border: 1px solid #005242;
        color: #fff;

    }
/* -------------------------------Section-Search------------------------------------ */
    .section-Search{
      background-color: #003027;
      border: 2px solid #003027;
      border-radius: 3px;
      position:relative;
      left:200px;
      right:20px;
      top: 500px;
      height: 30vh;
      width: 600px;
      z-index: 99;

}
   .main-Search{
padding:30px 10px;
  display: inline;

}

.col1{

}

.col3{


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styling.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/fonts/Aileron/">
      <title>Williams Rental Propertie's</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <!--- TOP LEFT-------->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="top-left">
      <ul>
        <li>  <i class="fas fa-phone-volume icon-contact ">(312)343-8748</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-envelope icon-contact">WilliamsRentalProperties</i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--- SOCIAL LINKS-------->
    <div class="social-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </a></i></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--- TOP RIGHT-------->
    <div class="top-right">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fas fa-user "> <a href="#"> Register</i></a></li>
          <li> <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"><a href="#">Login</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <!--- main Header-------->

    <div class="main-header">
      <div class="header-text">
        <h1>Williams <span> Rental</span> Properties</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="main-nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Featured List</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> About Us</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Pages</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>

  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Let Us Find You Your Dream Home!</h2>
        <p>Search real estate property records, houses, condos, land and more .
Find property info from the most comprehensive source data.</p>
     <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">View Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  </header>

  <section class ="section-Search">
    <div class="main-Search">
      <form class="Search" action="index.html" method="post">
        <label for="address"></label>

          <!--- city-------->
          <div class="col1">
        <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="keyword,zipcode">

        <label for="city"></label>
      <select class="city" name="city">
        <option value="city">city</option>
        </select>

        <label for="state"></label>
      <select class="state" name="state-form">
        <option value="state">state</option>
        </div>
    <!--- search button------->
    <a class="search-btn" href="#">Search</a>

      </select>


      </form>



  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this worked i got rid of the other divs and mad it one div. thanks

Comment: @Dsh You're welcome. Please up vote this answer and mark it as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of it.